# foreach loop to create a xml string

Tags: php, xml, foreach

I need to create a xml feed from an array with data, so im using a foreach loop to create it, but when i print_r the result, the only parts that prints out is the part before the foreach loop starts, i tested the array outside and it has data and its correctly diplayed

```
<PriceHeader>
                          <version>1.5.1</version>
                        </PriceHeader>';
                        foreach($sorted_data as $data){ 
                        '<Price>
                            <itemIdentifier>
                              <sku>'.$data["SKU"].'</sku>
                            </itemIdentifier>
                            <pricingList>
                                <pricing>
                                    <currentPrice>
                                        <value currency="USD" amount='.$data["Price"].'></value>
                                    </currentPrice>
                                </pricing>
                            </pricingList>
                        </Price>';
                        } 
                        '</PriceFeed>';
```

if i print_r that var, The only output i've got is 1.5.1, but inspecting element in chrome shows me that it creates the html structure as well, up to the point where the loop starts....

Comment: What are you expecting when you have things like `'</PriceFeed>';`?  I would also recommend creating the content using something like SimpleXML rather than building strings.

Comment: You cannot simply enclose a string in the loop. You need to enlose a command. So maybe an echo commend outputting that string.

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleXMLElement` in PHP. For more information, you can visit [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php)

Also, if you want to see your XML in your browser, you can use `htmlspecialchars` function with echo.

I tried to change your code as example.

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Have a nice coding :)

```
<?php
$string = "";
$string .="<PriceFeed>
<PriceHeader>
                          <version>1.5.1</version>
                        </PriceHeader>";
                        foreach($sorted_data as $data){

                        $string.= "<Price>
                            <itemIdentifier>
                              <sku>".$data["SKU"]."</sku>
                            </itemIdentifier>
                            <pricingList>
                                <pricing>
                                    <currentPrice>
                                        <value currency=\"USD\" amount=\"".$data["Price"]."\"></value>
                                    </currentPrice>
                                </pricing>
                            </pricingList>
                        </Price>";
                        }
                        $string.= "</PriceFeed>";



$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$output = $xml->asXML();

echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars($output);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: perfect, that worked better than mine, cause it was accepted by walmart feed, although i dont understand what $string .= means, is that for concatenation?

Comment: thank you. Yes it means concatenation of strings. Like that:
$str1 = "bla1"
$str2 = "bla2"
$str = $str1.$str2
[bla1bla2]

Comment: Why are you parsing and serializing the XML after creating the XML as text? That is an unnecessary step and does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating the xml string with XMLwriter, here is how the code ended:

```
$xw = xmlwriter_open_memory();
xmlwriter_set_indent($xw, 1);
$res = xmlwriter_set_indent_string($xw, ' ');

xmlwriter_start_document($w, '1.0', 'UTF-8');

xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'PriceFeed');
xmlwriter_start_attribute($xw, 'xmlns');
xmlwriter_text($xw, 'http://walmart.com/');
xmlwriter_end_attribute($xw);

xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'PriceHeader');
xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'version');
xmlwriter_text($xw, '1.5.1');
xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
xmlwriter_end_element($xw);

foreach($sorted_data as $data){
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'Price');
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'itemIdentifier');
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'sku');
    xmlwriter_text($xw, $data["SKU"]);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'pricingList');
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'pricing');
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'currentPrice');
    xmlwriter_start_element($xw, 'value');
    xmlwriter_start_attribute($xw, 'currency');
    xmlwriter_text($xw, 'USD');
    xmlwriter_start_attribute($xw, 'amount');
    xmlwriter_text($xw, $data['Price']);
    xmlwriter_end_attribute($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
    xmlwriter_end_element($xw);
}

xmlwriter_end_document($xw);

echo xmlwriter_output_memory($xw);
```